# what will happen when providing two pull up resistors in same line

Tags: microcontroller, pullup, open-drain

If two pull ups given in a situation one pull is 4.7 K-ohm and other pull up is 10 k-ohm was given to open-drain pin then what will happen? Imagine the open-drain was connecting to an IO pin of an external MCU  [image]

In open drain pin's device datasheet it was mentioned that open drain pin as input will handle max of 10 uA. In that case will that 1 mA damage the open drain pin ?  actually there will be current division right (or) will all current enterily flows towards the open-drain pin ? [image]

Comment: Ah, let me see. If the output IC is a switching MOSFET, and when switched on, then Vsd ~= 0V (Rds9on ~= 0) , so I output ~= Vsupply/Rpull-up. On the other hand Input depends on input resistance Rinput, Ic  ~= 0V / Rinput. ~= 0A. If fet switch of off. Then Iinput = Vsupply/ Rinput. Just thinking aloud, nothing proofread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have a pull-up of 4k7 || 10k = 3k2.

The open drain pin will have to handle a maximum current of *V / R = 3.3 / 3k2 = 1* mA.

> In open drain pin's device datasheet it was mentioned that open drain pin as input will handle max of 10 uA.

This sounds as though you are mis-reading it. It doesn't "handle" a current but may source or draw up to 10 μA. That means that the pull-up resistor would have to source 10 μA into the input to keep it high. That's not an issue.

> In that case will that 1 mA damage the open drain pin?

The open drain pin is on your "Output IC". Check the datsheet. It can probably sink 50 mA.

> ... actually there will be current division right (or) will all current entirely flows towards the open-drain pin ?

When the line is high the pull-up will supply 10 μA to the input.

When the line is low the pull-up will supply 1 mA to the open-drain transistor.

For almost all practical purposes you can ignore the input current for CMOS devices because it is so low for steady-state conditions. At high frequencies the situation changes because you have to charge and discharge the input capacitance.

Comment: Thanks for reply...Edited question again and asked one more question with picture in main question section itself

Comment: See the update.